# How to fix this unit test failure?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to write the unit tests for the below function(fetching some data from snowflake) but my unit test is failing and I am unable to figuring out the reason.

my function

```
import snowflake.connector 
from service.kms_utils import decrypt 

def get_data_from_snowflake(server_name):
    sql_query = f"Select * from mytable where servername={server_name}"
    server_details = []
    try:
        conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user=decrypt(os.environ.get('sfusername')),
        password=decrypt(os.environ.get('sfpwd')),
        account=decrypt(os.environ.get('account')),
        warehouse="wh1"
        )
    
        cs = conn.cursor().execute(sql_query)
        server_details= cs.fetchall()
        conn.close()
    
    except Exception as e:
        if "Could not connect to Snowflake Query backend after" in str(e):
            logger.error(f"Snowflake: Snowflake query timeout. {e}")
        elif "Failed to connect to DB" in str(e):
            logger.error(f"Snowflake: Snowflake DB connection error. {e}")
        else:
            logger.error(f"Snowflake: Failed to get CI validationm data. {e}")
return server_details
```

My unit test as below

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
from my_module import get_data_from_snowflake


@patch('snowflake.connector.connect')
def test_get_data_from_snowflake_success(mock_connect):
    #Mock the Snowflake connection object and cursor
    mock_cursor = MagicMock()
    mock_connect.return_value.cursor.return_value.execute.return_value = mock_cursor
    mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = [(1, 'Server1', 'Details1'), (2, 'Server2', 'Details2')]

    # Call the function being tested
    result = get_data_from_snowflake('Server1')

    # Check that the result is as expected
    assert result == [(1, 'Server1', 'Details1')]
```

But the assertion is failing as result is coming an empty list []. Error in decrypt function when decrypting string. You must specify a region.

Comment: could it be related to `sql_query = "Select * from mytable where servername=server_name"`? I guess you want to use `server_name `.
probably ```sql_query = f"Select * from mytable where servername='{server_name}'" ``` should work!

Comment: I have updated the question(f string added). But it should not matter what query getting passed in test as I am mocking the connection here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is stemming from your `decrypt` call, `Error in decrypt function when decrypting string. You must specify a region`. I see in the module import statements it references `KMS` which is an AWS service. Asking for a region is also an `AWS` traceback that I have seen many times before. You need to make sure to mock the functionality of `decrypt` actually reaching out to `AWS`.

If you are not interested in mocking this functionality, then you can set the following in your test:

```
def test_get_data_from_snowflake_success(mock_connect, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", "us-east-1")
```

My recommendation would be to not have it hit `AWS` but without more info on `decrypt` a more detailed answer is not possible.